# Previous Day's data using oracle 11g

Tags: sql, performance, date, plsql, oracle11g

Currently I am fetching data for every 1 hour using this:

```
create_date >= sysdate -1/24
```

When the process runs at midnight 12:00 am and the date changes to next day, is there anyway in Oracle to pick up data entered between 11pm to 12 am the previous day.

Thanks

Comment: Your query should be doing that.  If not, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not run the SQL at midnight then  you can use trunc function to do what you want like this :

```
 create_date between trunc(sysdate) - 1/24 and trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the process every hour, you will pick up the previous hour. For example, if you run at 12:10 AM, your clause will pick up everything from 11:10 PM of the previous day to 12:10 AM of the current day.

If you have to be sure to pick up absolutely everything, I suggest that you change your logic. If you don't, and your procedure doesn't run for some reason, such as the database is down for maintenance, you will miss processing some records

When your procedure starts, capture the current date/time and store it in a table. When your procedure runs, fetch that date and use that last value as your start value:

```
create_date between last_date and procedure_start_date
```